# Wi-fi in Kali Dual-Boot not working

Tags: wifi, drivers, kali-linux, internet, macintosh

I installed Kali on my MacBook Air (Mid-2013) through a bootable USB with persistence. However, I am unable to connect to Wifi. Infact, the build does not even show any Wifi/WLAN settings or show a method to connect, it just acts as if I don't have WiFi.

I tried following the instructions, but they didn't help at all: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?26670-Kali-2-0-Installation-Tips-for-Macbook-Pro-2015-Retina

How can I fix this issue.

NOTE: I am pretty sure the issue is in the WiFi drivers. I also don't have an ethernet port on my computer so I won't be able to download anything right into KALI.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1):

MacBooks use a firmware file called Broadcom for their Broadcom wireless cards. In order to get this installed with no internet, do the following (no  internet access):

Download the [b43updated.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/19e7y7w6ndozdzq/b43_updated.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAEELVjeW3iSm3d0ScTg17BSplJ01qhPGCkhav5o9EYiJA&expiry=1400713892) file to a usb flash drive from a computer that already has internet, then drag and drop the file to your Kali desktop. Right-click it and select Extract Here.

Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo mkdir /lib/firmware/b43
sudo cp Desktop/b43_updated.zip/*  /lib/firmware/b43
sudo modprobe -rv b43 
sudo modprobe -v b43
```

if it does not come on reboot.

From [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470153/no-wireless-when-install-14-04-on-macbook-pro).

Comment: I edit your post, Ben. It is a firmware file /binary blob, the actual driver per se is the kernel module. Modded you up too.

Comment: Rui, I'm not sure what you meant in your comment. Did you already edit the post or should I make those changes? If I have to make the changes, how would I do this? Can u please clarify what u mean in that case because I didn't understand it.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the post and nothing changed.

Comment: @thefool can you edit your response to include the output of `lspci -v` as well as the output of `dmesg | grep iwl`. This will tell us some more information about your system and information about wifi drivers/firmware during start up.

Answer (score 0):

1) Find the network device by

```
  spci -nn | grep -i network
```

2) verify the kernel module

```
  lspci -k | grep -i network -A 2
```

for example the output : Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
If you don't have any infos about kernel module , you need to install it, connect to internet using cable eth open package manager and type bcm (the easy way)

3) For Desktop gnome >> install network-manager

KDE desktop >> install plasma-widget-networkmanagement

4) command line

```
 ifconfig wlan0 down

 ifconfig wlan0 up
```

If you can't find Wifi-connection maybe you need to reboot